# How do I add customer attributes in Magento 2 CE?

Tags: magento2, attributes, custom, customer-attribute

In `Magento 2 CE` we have to add new attributes with Coding? It's not provided by default?

I have looked in to http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/magento-2-make-customer-attribute.html

I would like to add custom customer attribute called "passport" in Magento 2 CE.

I also like to apply validation of that on both side client & server. Through jQuery regexp we can achieve this. But the main concern is where to add/in which file so it will not affect other things

Comment: can you send me email id. so i can do it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Here is the update http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/130914/magento-2-custom-customer-attribute-not-showing-on-frontend

Answer (score 4):

### Place this code in InstallData Script in custom module.

InstallData.php

```
namespace Paarth\CustomerAttribute\Setup;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{ 

    private $customerSetupFactory;      

    public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
    {
      $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface
    $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */

        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $setup->startSetup();

        $attributeCode = "passport";

        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode);          

        $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer',
        'passport', [
        'label' => 'Passport',
        'type' => 'text',
        'frontend_input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
         'system'=> 0,
        'position' => 105,
        ]);

        $loyaltyAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'passport');
        $loyaltyAttribute->setData('used_in_forms',['adminhtml_customer']);
        $loyaltyAttribute->save();

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Comment: Added @Paarth. Not working. Not showing in DB as well :(. Internal messages between users not allowed.

Comment: Did you change namespace ?

Comment: Nope. I think tutorial only missing registration.php file. So i have added that & it works well. Thank you for help & effort at well. Appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks Mike.  can you send me skype Id or email address.

Comment: There is no internal messaging system. How to do it?

Comment: Doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Use `$customerSetup` (solution by @Paarth) and add `'adminhtml_only' => true` as a part of attribute configuration instead of

```
$loyaltyAttribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute('customer', 'passport');   
$loyaltyAttribute->setData('used_in_forms',['adminhtml_customer']);
$loyaltyAttribute->save();
```

You can also add `'is_used_in_grid' => true` if you want it to be available in grid

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace Eg\Solution\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig       = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'loyal_customer',
            [
                'type'         => 'int',
                'label'        => 'Loyal Customer',
                'input'        => 'boolean',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'global' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL',
                'required'     => false,
                'visible'      => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'position'     => 999,
                'system'       => 0,
            ]
        );
            $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
                CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
                null,
                'loyal_customer');
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'loyal_customer');

        // more used_in_forms ['adminhtml_checkout','adminhtml_customer','adminhtml_customer_address','customer_account_edit','customer_address_edit','customer_register_address']
        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer']

        );
        $sampleAttribute->getResource()->save($sampleAttribute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all create a sample module called `Mageplaza_HelloWorld` and the `InstallDataclass.`

then,create `InstallData.php` file

on `app/code/Mageplaza/Example/Setup/InstallData.php`

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\Example\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

}
```

In this class, we define the EAV setup model which will be use to interact with Magento 2 attribute.

After that, we have to define the `install()` method and create eav setup model:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
    }
    Next, we will use eavSetup object to add attribute:
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Sample Attribute',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'required' => true,
                'default' => '0',
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'system' => false,
                'position' => 100
            ]
        );
}
```

Finally, we need to set the forms in which the attributes will be used. In this step, we need define the eavConfig object which allow us to call the attribute back and set the data for it. And the full code to create customer attribute is:

File: `app/code/Mageplaza/Example/Setup/InstallData.php`

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\Example\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory, Config $eavConfig)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'sample_attribute',
            [
                'type' => 'int',
                'label' => 'Sample Attribute',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'required' => true,
                'default' => '0',
                'sort_order' => 100,
                'system' => false,
                'position' => 100
            ]
        );
        $sampleAttribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'sample_attribute');
        $sampleAttribute->setData(
            'used_in_forms',
            ['adminhtml_customer_address', 'customer_address_edit', 'customer_register_address']
        );
        $sampleAttribute->save();
    }
}
```

Now, let run command line to install the module: `php magento setup:upgrade`. Then check the customer page to see the new attribute.

I hope it helps you !!

Comment: this also didn't helped

Comment: This answer was blatantly plagiarised from the [top post on google](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html) and is in essence the same method as an earlier, neater answer.

Comment: I used following extension
https://github.com/diglin/Diglin_Username2

And it is just working fine. I want to update/set the custom attribute of customer value programmatically & save it in database. This is not working. Can you suggest me some technique/procedure to achieve this....