# Magento 2 Custom Customer Attribute not Showing on Frontend [Solved]

Tags: magento2, customer, controllers, frontend, customer-attribute

I'm able to add custom customer attribute called "passport".

It's working fine on Admin Side. So no issues.

For the frontend however it's not displaying on Registration page.

Below code already added InstallData.php

> 'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register',
>   'customer_account_create',
>   'customer_account_edit','adminhtml_checkout'],

So, for frontend, i have created Block - Widget  for that Passport Field & Overriding Customer Registration Page. It's already pointing to New File.

> \magento2\app\code\Custom\CustomerAttribute\Block\Widget\Passport.php

```
public function _construct() {  
    parent::_construct();             

$this->setTemplate('Custom_CustomerAttribute::widget/passport.phtml'); 
 }
```

> \magento2\app\code\Custom\CustomerAttribute\view\frontend\templates\form\register.phtml

```
<?php
$_passport = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Custom\CustomerAttribute\Block\Widget\Passport');
if ($_passport->isEnabled()):
    echo $_passport->setPassport($block->getFormData()->getPassport())->toHtml();
endif;
?>
```

While running above code it's not calling `<project path>\magento2\app\code\Custom\CustomerAttribute\view\frontend\templates\widget\passport.phtml` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer & solution.

> \magento2\app\code\Custom\CustomerAttribute\Block\Widget\Passport.php

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isEnabled() {
    $attributeMetadata = $this->_getAttribute('passport');
    return $attributeMetadata ? (bool) $attributeMetadata->isVisible() : false;
}
```

Now it's displaying in frontend :)

Comment: have you created extension Custom/CustomerAttribute

Comment: @ankit - Can you plz share your Widget\Passport.php, actually I am doing same but  don't know why getting error.

Comment: It's already mentioned in question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88245/magento2-create-a-customer-custom-attribute